# Counter value based on last environments

Tags: conditionals

How to put the condition using TeX macros that rule should enabled only last `test` environment alone?

Suppose the document contain only one `\begin{test}...\end{test}`
rule should be enabled.

If multiple `\begin{test}...\end{test}` contain in the document rule should be enabled only last `\begin{test}...\end{test}` alone.

Please find my MWE file:

```
\documentclass{book}
\pagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifruletest\global\ruletestfalse
\newcounter{testcounter}
\setcounter{testcounter}{0}

\newenvironment{test}{\noindent\parindent0pt}
{\par\stepcounter{testcounter}
\ifnum\value{testcounter}>0\rule{\textwidth}{1bp}\global\ruletestfalse\else\fi\bigskip}


\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{test}
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
\end{test}

\begin{test}
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
\end{test}

\begin{test}
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
\end{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of test with a counter is positive, you can test if a boolean is true.

Comment: please show example based on my MWE

Comment: Do you want a rule only after the last test block? Even if a single one had been used?

Comment: Yes, I need rule for last block in the document, at same time single test block in the document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `totcount`; two runs of LaTeX are needed if the number of `test` environments changes.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{totcount}

\newtotcounter{testcounter}

\newenvironment{test}
 {\par\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}}
 {\par\stepcounter{testcounter}
  \ifnum\totvalue{testcounter}=\value{testcounter}%
    \nobreak\rule{\textwidth}{1bp}\bigskip
  \fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
\end{test}

\begin{test}
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
\end{test}

\begin{test}
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
\end{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, this is I want exactly, Thank you.